# VM screen too small for Selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-testing

Hi Im having an issue with my selenium tests on my vm. All my fails are due to the screen being too small (im checking with screenshots)

Ive tried numerous things:
!. Maximize screen
2. Set the screen size in selenium
3. Expanded the resolution on the vm

But non of these are working. Ive also tried similar questions mentioned here but to no avail.

My vm is connected by a Connected via JNLP agent (wont connect ay other way) and running windows 10, and my tests have to be run on chrome. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Expanded the resolution on the vm" - why didn't his work? Can you add more details?

Comment: My dev ops went in and changed the resolution but nothing has changed in the tests, as far as i know he just changed this int he display settings